click allow cookies popup on firefox selenium c#
I want to click on allow option which is coming out from a pop up of a website ,I want to do on firefox to allow cookies:

i try this code but not work :
FirefoxDriverService cService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(".", "geckodriver.exe");
cService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArgument("ignore-certificate-errors");
options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + FolderPathToStoreSession);

options.AddArgument("--disable-notifications");
options.AddArguments("Firefox.switches", "--disable-extensions");
//options.AddArguments ("profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", "1");
options.SetPreference("network.cookie.cookieBehavior", "0");
options.SetPreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.cookies", "1");
          

also i try alert :
   var alert = driver_Ref.SwitchTo().Alert();
   
alert.Accept();

but not work, it seems to be this is not alert,
how to click allow in popup, or allow it automatically

Please be careful when selecting tags. Just pressing a single letter, like c, will likely give you the wrong one. Like the C language tag instead of C#.

i did not found a programmatically solution , but i can do it manually by open Firefox profile, then go to about:preferences#privacy and change enhance tracking protection to custom and in cookies option select cross site tracking cookies like this:

now the popup message not appears again
,if anyone found how to do that in  options.SetPreference(...) please share it
